# How to send multiple json request body with single api with mutiple parameters using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load, web-api-testing, jmeter-5.0

How to send multiple json request body with single api with mutiple parameters

Hi,

I want to hit an api with single user, mutiple json body(500) request should execute single time using parameterization and should save it in database as a single record.

Comment: Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to build single large HTTP Request out of 500 JSON files you need to use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and concatenate 500 files into a single request body.

1. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the request which payload you want to parameterize
2. Use [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) to read files from the filesystem and [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) for generating the output JSON
3. Use `vars` shorthand to store the value into a JMeter Variable like:

   ```
   vars.put('payload', jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
   ```
4. Use `${payload}` in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler body data tab.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: In this case i want to parameterize mutliple data also, does parameterization concept works here! ur  help would be great!